# Will a lower input Ampere harm my laptop?

Tags: laptop, charger

My original charger has an input ampere of `1.6 A` whereas the replacement I am planning to buy has an input ampere of `1.5 A`. I'd like to know if this `.1` difference would make any huge change or harm my laptop.

**Specs**
Original Charger:-
Input 100-240V ~1.6A 50-60Hz | Output 18.5V 3.5A 65W | Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm

Replacement Charger:-
Input 100-240V ~1.5A 50-60Hz | Output 18.5V 3.5A 65W | Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm

Comment: The important part is output Voltage plus Output Ampere. What are these on both chargers?

Comment: You should be more worried that your laptop would damage the charger.  You need to match the Amperage.

Comment: @Marki555 all the other values are same on both the chargers.

Comment: @user1928108 - What are those values exactly?  We cannot tell you if its safe if you don't indicate what the voltage output is on both chargers.

Comment: @Ramhound Output values :- 18.5V 3.5 A

Comment: @Marki555 nope let me lay it out for ya :- 
Original Charger:-
Input 100-240V ~1.6A 50-60Hz
Output 18.5V 3.5A 65 W
Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm

Replacement Charger 
Original Charger:-
Input 100-240V ~1.5A 50-60Hz
Output 18.5V 3.5A 65W
Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the details provided in comment by OP:

> Original Charger
>
> - Input 100-240V ~1.6A 50-60Hz
> - Output 18.5V 3.5A 65 W Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm
>
> Replacement Charger
>
> - Input 100-240V ~1.5A 50-60Hz
> - Output 18.5V 3.5A 65W Pin Size 7.4 x 5.0mm

They can be safely used as they both have the same output voltage and output current and are rated for 65 watts.

The stated input current (amperage) is probably the max. current it can draw or the value of its internal fuse. The actual average input current is about 0.35A for countries with 240V and about 0.65A for coutries with 110V (you just need to divide the watts by voltage and add 10-20% for losses).

Answer (score 2):

Amperage is what the laptop "pulls" from the AC adapter. If the laptop is rated as 1.6 amps, that is the max it will pull from the adapter under its heaviest load.

Using an adapter that is rated lower (1.5) than the laptop can work. The only caution is that under full load the laptop will want more amps than the adapter can provide. This may cause the adapter to be over worked and burn out prematurely. For this reason, it is recommended to get an adapter that is rated the same or higher.

Comment: Usually the laptop can communicate with the charger and won't try to pull more. You can also get original smaller travel chargers.

Comment: @Marki555 This may be true in *some* cases, the OP has not given any specifics about equipment for us to know if that is the case here.

Comment: I have added the exact info in the OT.

Comment: The two adapters have the same output characteristics (voltage, current, power), so the concern about higher load is not relevant (assuming the original adapter is the correct one).

The difference in input current (1.5A vs 1.6A) is most likely a rounding error, or the new adapter being slightly more efficient.